# How to make VLC the default player on the Chrome browser?

Tags: google-chrome, media-player, media, default

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
 </head>

 <body>
  <a href="http://test/video/dal.m4v">
  <img src="http://webserver/images/movies.png" width="186" height="184" border="none" >
  </a>
 </body>
</html>
```

When users click the image I would like for my video to play in the VLC player. My users will be using the Chrome browser. I would like VLC to be the default media player in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Simple, just use udp instead of http in your URI. This is what we call a [URI scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme).

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/zf359/1/

Here is the simple code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
 </head>

 <body>
  <a href="udp://test/video/dal.m4v">
  <img src="http://webserver/images/movies.png" width="186" height="184" border="none" >
  </a>
 </body>
</html>
```

It won't guaranty that VLC will load every time. But it should work on the machines that have VLC installed. Also it will only work for servers that support udp.

Or you could use m3u for more details: [Open VLC Network Streaming from web browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21817510/open-vlc-network-streaming-from-web-browser)